# Dynamic addition of div using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I am a beginner in angularjs.
I want to dynamically add a div while clicking on add icon.I have done some script on this .

HTML part:

```
<div ng-show="child" class="childDiv" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index">
    <label for="childname" class="childname"  >ServerName </label>
    <input  ng-model="serverinfo.childname" type="text" required="required"  placeholder="name"/>
    <label for="childname" class="childname"  >Fullname</label>
    <input  ng-model="serverinfo.childfullname" type="text" required="required"  placeholder="fullname"/>
    <label for="childname" class="childname"  >Mandatory Field</label>
    <input  ng-model="serverinfo.field" type="text" required="required"  placeholder="city/county.."/>
    <label for="childname" class="childname"  >Field values</label>
    <input  ng-model="serverinfo.value" type="text" required="required"  placeholder=""/>
    <i ng-click="removechild()" ng-show="$last" style="padding-left:16em;" class="material-icons">remove</i>                                    
</div>
<i ng-click="addchild()" style="padding-left:16em;" class="material-icons">add</i>
```

JS part:

```
$scope.addchild  = function() {
    //  $scope.child = true;
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
};

$scope.removechild  = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
};
```

My output is like this,[image]

My issue is like whatever I input in the textbox, it will automatically copy to the next set. Can anyone figure out the issue.

Comment: Why do you always bind the values to `serverinfo`? Shouldn't you bind it to `choice in`?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i will try to implement that

Comment: You should know that after this change you won't have anything inside `$scope.serverinfo`. If you want to use `serverinfo` in the controller then you should use `serverinfo[ $index ].yourPropertyName` instead - This will give you an array where the properties of the elements in the `$scope.serverinfo` array match the choices in `$scope.choices` respectively

Comment: Thank you it worked

Comment: Alon can you post this as an answer

Comment: You're welcome. I have edited my last comment because  I wrote it wrong

Comment: Yes, I'll write a description

Comment: Please don't mix ngModel and ngRepeat. What you should be doing instead is having a separate variable tied to your form, then pushing to your array. An example is comments on an article or something like that.

Comment: @cst1992 Nothing wrong with mixing `ngModel` and `ngRepeat` as long as you make sure that you're binding the expressions to different objects (See the answers to this question, they are all demonstrating how to do it correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently binding all the values to the same object `serverinfo`, and because you're inside a loop (`ng-repeat`) then each field in the loop is bound to the same object in the controller.

You have two options:

**Bind the fields to the `choice` element:**

```
<div ng-show="child" class="childDiv" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index">
    <input  ng-model="choice.childname" type="text" required="required"  placeholder="name"/>
</div>
```

The above will bind the properties to each choice directly, and will be available in the controller via `console.log( $scope.choices[0].childname );`

**Use the `$index` indicator to create an array of matched choices:**

This is a good solution for cases when you don't want to overwrite/change the values of the original array.

```
<div ng-show="child" class="childDiv" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index" ng-init="serverinfo[ $index ].id = choice.id">
    <input  ng-model="serverinfo[ $index ].childname" type="text" required="required"  placeholder="name"/>
</div>
```

The above will bind the properties to a new array object name `serverinfo`, where each element is relative to a choice in `$scope.choices`, it will be available in the controller via `console.log( $scope.serverinfo[0].childname );`

Note that I also added `ng-init="serverinfo[ $index ].id = choice.id"` to copy the `id` property of each choice to the new array elements that are dynamically created by the `ngRepeat` directive loop.

Comment: Hey, in your previous comment of that "edit saved" thing, I didn't understand what you meant?

Comment: @PraveenKumar On that post that was just deleted?

Comment: Yup, that same one.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Just a sarcastic comment to the editor that changed `i'm` to `I'm` and same capitalization to the comment :)

Comment: Ha ha. Sorry mate, I understand it is sarcastic, but I didn't understand it. Like, yea... Well, still didn't understand. Ha ha.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I just remembered [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345631/user-consciously-ignores-the-rules-of-asking-questions-on-so-what-to-do-about-i#comment457684_345632) so I wanted to let them understand that they should not do unneccacery edits (Eddited the link)

Answer (score 1):

using your repeated item name "choice" instead of serverInfo should solve the issue

```
                       <div ng-show="child" class="childDiv" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index">
                                        <label for="childname" class="childname"  >ServerName </label>
                                        <input  ng-model="choice.childname" type="text" required="required"  placeholder="name"/>
                                        <label for="childname" class="childname"  >Fullname</label>
                                        <input  ng-model="choice.childfullname" type="text" required="required"  placeholder="fullname"/>
                                        <label for="childname" class="childname"  >Mandatory Field</label>
                                        <input  ng-model="choice.field" type="text" required="required"  placeholder="city/county.."/>
                                        <label for="childname" class="childname"  >Field values</label>
                                        <input  ng-model="choice.value" type="text" required="required"  placeholder=""/>
                                        <i ng-click="removechild()" ng-show="$last" style="padding-left:16em;" class="material-icons">remove</i>

                                </div>
                                <i ng-click="addchild()" style="padding-left:16em;" class="material-icons">add</i>
```

Comment: And where do you have this serverInfo, What is serverInfo, its only seen in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are binding same ng model to each repeating object. put

```
 ng-model="choice.childname"
```

Do same for other inputs. And if you want serverinfo to contain all this values than copy it.