# Angularjs: Datepicker is not working in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am using one template for my project which provide a class named *input-datepicker* , by applying this class name on input element ,popup of datepicker gets open .

When i use same class inside ng-repeat it doesn't work. What would be your advice about this problem ?
I have used directives also

```
var app=angular.module('module', []).directive("datepicker", function () {
 function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    // CALL THE "datepicker()" METHOD USING THE "element" OBJECT.
    element.datepicker({
        // dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });
 }
 return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: link
 };
})
```

Note : the input field where im applying the class is inside modal.
Below Html COde:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in array">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-datepicker" ng-mode="user.date" />
```

Comment: can you show the html code?

Comment: Don't waste your time implementing the jQuery datepicker, use the [native version](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker) of datepicker

Comment: But 80% of the project has the jquery Datepicker

Comment: @SiddheshMishra Ok, so in your HTML you're binding all the dates to the same model `user.date` you should bind it to `x.date` for example

Comment: Oh shoot, it was supposed to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609770/dynamic-addition-of-div-using-ng-repeat-in-angularjs/43610175.

Comment: @SiddheshMishra `ng-mode` should be `ng-model` and then you have to manually update `ng-model` value on datepicker change event, you can refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29194068/2435473), though it is datetimepicker.

Comment: @AlonEitan no..if i use x.date ..then too it is not popping up

Comment: @PankajParkar Sir sorry for my wrong spell...i am in hurry so did that